# Linear Algebra Matrix Skew Symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

Recall that an nxn matrix is called skew-symmetric if A^T=-A.
a)Prove that for all x that are in R^n we have x^TAx=0 (note: x^T Ax is a scalar for any nxn matrix A)
b) Prove that I+A is invertible

My professor assigned a bunch of questions prior to our exam and I feel as though they haven't been adequately covered throughout the semester. I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Questions that look like you desperately want us to do your homework for you are not usually well received here. Why don't you edit your title, and show us some effort in the question?

Comment: (a) $x^TAx=(x^TAx)^T=x^TA^Tx=-x^TAx$. Therefore $2x^TAx=0$, from where it follows that $x^TAx=0$. (b) If $(I+A)x=0$. Then $0=x^T(I+A)x=x^Tx+x^TAx=x^Tx=\|x\|^2$. Therefore $x=0$.

Comment: @user647486:  That is an answer, not a comment.  If you want to post it, please make it an answer.  I generally prefer not to give a full answer to what I think are homework problems unless I find them interesting, but it is your call.  Making it an answer makes it more permanent and searchable.

Comment: @Katrina Some skills in mathematics are not really content that needs to be covered, but ideas that need to be acquired from experience, from seeing others use them. In (a) you were told already. Exploit symmetries that the problem has. In (b) there is a combination of many ideas that are useful in many places of linear algebra: (1)  The equivalence between invertible and trivial kernel. (2) Proving that vectors are zero by computing its norm. (3) Taking dot product.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  the fact that you know something about the transpose of $A$ suggests that taking the transpose of something in the problem will be productive.